# Is it possible in Lua to bind an argument to a callback function passed as argument to another function? (JavaScript's "bind" equivalent)

Tags: lua

I have a third party API that has an event listener adding function which takes as parameter a callback function to be triggered when the event occurs. I would like to pass argument to that callback function. I'm looking for Lua's equivalent of JavaScript's `bind`.

The Lua code:

```
EventListenerAddingFunction(myCallbackFunction); // I want to add a param to the callback here
```

How I would do it in JS:

```
EventListenerAddingFunction(myCallbackFunction.bind({}, myParameter));
```

Can this be done in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Lua doesn't have this feature, so closest I can think of would be making a closure-wrapper:

```lua
EventListenerAddingFunction(function(...) myCallbackFunction({}, myParameter, ...) end)
```

This passes your parameter everytime the callback is called, all other callback parameters will be passed next. If you don't know your parameters use `...` (I don't know them so I used varargs), it's better if you pass exact amount of parameters.